# Combining Optoisolator and Relay into one I/O pin

Tags: microcontroller, relay, opto-isolator

I have a project that uses two microcontroller pins to control the input and output of an isolated device.  The LEDs are for status, showing when an input or output is enabled.

I'd like to save some I/O pins and I was wondering how to approach combining these together to use a single microcontroller pin?

[image: The Circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. You must have a very small relay to be able to drive it directly from the uC pin. You should have a **Schottky** catch diode across the relay coil. If you use a driver transistor you can use a regular diode as below.

The method would be something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUiXKT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To measure the input, tristate the MCU I/O pin for (say) 5 microseconds. It will go high or low depending on Q1 (the optoisolator output). Grab the value and return the pin to its desired state. Repeat the polling relatively infrequently (say at 200Hz). The relay will have insufficient time to drop out or pull in.

Note that the above circuit has the relay energized for output high rather than low.

Generally though, it's often better to move to a micro with a surfeit of pins rather than trying to cram everything into a few. There is inevitably a new feature or function that could use an extra pin.

Comment: Could you explain what's R2 and R3 are doing here?  Also if the input goes high, will it not turn on the mosfet?

Comment: R2 is a pullup for the opto. R3 isolates the MCU pin so it can drive M1 high or low independent of the opto state. If the MCU pin was driven low and the input is high, tristating the pin *will* turn on the MOSFET during that brief few microseconds and the relay will start to pull in. The key is to drive it back low before the relay gets a chance to respond. This will cause a bit of EMI from the relay coil.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Since this doesn't seem to be a high power setup, you could put an RC on the MOSFET gate to keep it from switching temporarily during the measurement cycle. It will slow the relay operation a bit, but a few msec doesn't seem likely to be a problem.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Sure, that would kill the relay switching entirely. A Schmitt trigger buffer could be used too.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Since this seems to be a pretty low-frequency switching app, I don't think he'd even need a Schmitt trigger, since the increased power dissipation due to slower gate transitions are probably not an issue. Depends on the details, of course.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast So long as the pull-in speed isn't compromised too much such that the contacts wear excessively. As you say- details. There's hysteresis built into the mechanical arrangement anyway.

Comment: One other point to consider: the catch diode slows the relay release considerably.  You can safely remove drive from most relays for several hundred microseconds without the relay contacts ever moving.  Spehro is using single-digit microseconds - no problem at all.

Comment: @DwayneReid - Yeah. I just hate to depend on things I haven't measured, is all.

Comment: I understand.  I **have** done those measurements - what Spehro Pefhany describes is standard practice in many of my designs.

Comment: As Dwayne says- there are numbers in some of the better (especially Japanese) relay datasheets. Having misspent many not-so-happy hours reading the aforementioned documents and reconciling them with actual testing..

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, bidirectional use of a microcontroller i/o would be really hard. I think the easiest way to have more i/o's is a port expander, which you can connect on a serial bus.

If you have multiple isolated devices you could also work with a shift register, but this will result in almost the same as a port expander via spi.

If you really need to only use one pin, here the idea; you have an astable multivibrator. One state for output one for input. When writing the output, you set the the input line on a tristate. So while you are "writing" the output (open collector of the ic and a pull up), the tristate is high. You store your data in a d flip flop for the output. After a defined time you switch your output pin to a input pin and you disconnect the d flip flop from the line (transistor). Now the output is set and you can read, for this the astable multivibrator activates the tristate and switches it to a open collector. Only thing left now is the synchronization, this would be more complicated, you could make a counter from 1 to 3, in the third state there is a short synchronization signal, so it wouldn't lose track. But you see, for this effort you can also use a port expander and you don't have to worry about i/o's then.

Comment: Lots of bad advice here.  1) One of the most powerful strengths of microcontrollers is the ease with which an input and output can be shared on a single I/O pin.  Read up on a term called "Charlieplexing" for more info - it's really easy to have both switches and LEDs crammed into a tiny number of pins.

Comment: Note that Charlieplexing is only one technique - Spehro Pefhany shows another common technique: relies upon the mechanical inertia or lack of response to fast events and quickly switch a pin from output to input; sample the input; return the pin back to output at the original state (Hi or Lo).  And there are other techniques as well.

Comment: Could you make an example of how charlieplexing would work with one pin for an input and output? As far as I know, charlieplexing is used for multiple outputs. From my point of view what you suggest is non-sense. Excuse me if im wrong, but I can't imagine a working circuit.

Comment: Charlieplexing does not work for a single pin.  I was addressing your initial statement: you said "Hmm, bidirectional use of a microcontroller i/o would be really hard."  That statement is **NOT** correct.  Your 3rd paragraph regarding the use of an astable multivibrator is simply not good advice.  It would take several paragraphs to describe all the reasons why this is bad advice.